# defining the architecture specific cordova plugin libraries to use in capacitor/react project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova-plugins, capacitor, ionic-react

As has been mentioned in https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/Building.md#apple-store-submission in order to submit the app to App Store we need to strip simulator (i386/x86_64) archs from WebRTC binary and as the very last step to do so it says:

Remove ios cordova platform if already added and add ios platform again (e.g. with a command cordova platform remove ios && cordova platform add ios) or remove and add only the plugin at your own risk.

I have a capacitor/react project in which I am using the above mentioned cordova plugin. And unfortunately you can not use cordova commands in capacitor/react environments!

How can I invoke such command in a capacitor/react project or is there any equivalent steps I can take to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are cordova instructions, for Capacitor just run `npx cap update ios` or `npx cap sync ios`

Comment: I have tried all those many times but unfortunately I still get the following message when I want to run it on a real device!  d: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'WebRTC'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCMediaConstraints", referenced from:

Comment: One can find the details of how to fix this issue @ https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3299